# What is a Riley riddle?

Tags: discussion

So I heard about [this riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/62349/my-prefix-is-food-my-suffix-is-rude), and people are making these types of riddles.

## ***What is a Riley riddle, and how can I make it?***

Answer (score 10):

A Riley riddle is simply a riddle following the pattern of the one you linked, as posted originally by the user Riley. The original rhymed, however most of the successive ones do not. There is no other real requirement to make a Riley Riddle.

There has been discussion of "Rileys" getting their own tag, as per the meta question: [Do "prefix-suffix-infix" riddles deserve their own tag?](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6275/do-prefix-suffix-infix-riddles-deserve-their-own-tag)

Comment: I have a question, why does the riley riddle have not its own tag?

Comment: @Dranier You can look at the linked meta post for the reasons. There is no consensus, but some argue that the tags "riddle", "wordplay", "word" are sufficient.

Comment: Note for future viewers: there is now a tag for Riley Riddles, [[tag:affix-riddle]] -> https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6989/now-that-theyve-become-so-popular-should-we-reconsider-creating-a-specific-cat

Answer (score 7):

Find a word's definition you can defend,
Then describe its beginning, middle, and end 
With wordplay involved,
Though some have evolved
From a [Riley](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/62349/my-prefix-is-food-my-suffix-is-rude) into a [Tyobrien](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/64120/word-riddle-you-love-me-or-you-hate-me)

:^)