# Is there a public discussion somewhere where some users decided that the tag Riley-riddle should be created?

Tags: discussion, support, tags

There have been some meta post where users discuss whether or not a new tag should be made for riddles that go like [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/62349/my-prefix-is-food-my-suffix-is-rude?noredirect=1&lq=1). The result was that it wasn't necessary. Recently, before I knew about the meta post, I created a [riley-riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/riley-riddle) tag, which was then removed by a user, sharing the link to the post in a comment.

Just [5 days ago](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tags/affix-riddle/info) from now, the tag was recreated by another user (I only found out today).

My question is, did the tag just pop out and everybody agreed that it was going to stay, or is there another public discussion somewhere else where some users decided that the tag should be created?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes... ish

In the most recent [should-we-have-a-tag meta question](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6989), Jeremy Dover added an update:

> **UPDATE** by [Jeremy Dover](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/69217/jeremy-dover)
> This question seems to have hit the point of inertia with no significant objection, other than the practicality of retagging several hundred old posts. I have gone ahead and created an [affix-riddle] tag, and applied it to the (as of 30 Sept 2020) recent active examples. Hopefully folks who author these riddles will use this tag in addition to the more generic [riddle] tag in the future.

He notified the main site chat [at the time](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/14524?m=55697114#55697114):

> Apologies for being the cranky old man, but a Riley riddle popped up in my feed, and I found myself doing it even though I really don't like them. Per the discussion on Meta, I went ahead and created an affix-riddle tag, and assigned it. (Affix is the generic term, per Wikipedia, which as we know is always accurate.)

And I've been adding the tag to any posts I notice without it since then.

Comment: +1 Thanks bobble. In the comments of the original post, Deusovi commented that the name "riley-riddle" was not really appropriate, since Riley is a proper name, and not descriptive of the genre. Since "prefix-infix-suffix-riddle" seemed unwieldy, and not necessarily definitive (see [Lukas Rotter's extension](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/101691/riley-riddle-taken-two-steps-further)), the more generic term affix-riddle seemed to fit the bill.