# New Category for "Tyo" riddles?

Tags: discussion, tags

Recently, user [TyoBrien](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/46277/tyobrien) posted a [new type of wordplay riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/64120/word-riddle-you-love-me-or-you-hate-me). His template has been used by more than 8 different users to date who created similar riddles. Examples: [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/64353/a-very-hard-anti-tyos-riddle), [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/64542/a-crimson-fish-tyo), and [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/65356/what-am-i-a-tyo-riddle).

Should we create a new tag for these riddles? What would we call it?

Answer (score 4):

**I don't think we need a new tag**, for the same reasons I give in the [“prefix-suffix-infix” riddles meta question](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6275/do-prefix-suffix-infix-riddles-deserve-their-own-tag) (I believe this is an identical situation).

Again, this is just one specific construction of a riddle using one specific example of wordplay. There are plenty of other examples of riddles that use the technique of adding/dropping letters, describing the results as it transforms ([1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/47559/you-think-you-have-it-bad), [2](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/31970/the-five-friends?rq=1), [3](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/59361/i-am-part-of-your-body), [4](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/13257/me-and-my-gang), [5](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/56537/a-place-to-obtain-whats-left), [6](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/25731/what-am-i-i-always-play-fair), [7](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/27617/lost-my-eyes-a-riddle), [8](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/57831/how-to-get-water-from-numbers), ...).

<sup>(See also related things like [word-ladder](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-ladder) and [reverse hangman](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=hangman))</sup>